# configure server and create website without any control panel

Tags: linux

i am trying to configure my new server without cpanel

i've installed php/mysql/apache

And it's now working fine

if you visit the server ip

http://46.166.129.101/

you'll see the welcome page

i've configured my dns too

my nameserverips file

```
[root@server]# cat /etc/nameserverips
46.166.129.101=ns1.isellsoftwares.com
46.166.129.101=ns2.isellsoftwares.com
```

if you visit this link http://ns1.isellsoftwares.com

you'll see the welcome page too!!

but if you visit isellsoftwares.com

you'll see ( 'Firefox can't find the server at www.isellsoftwares.com.' )

Now my question is: How to create an account for this domain on the server??

i've tryied to add virtualHost tag in apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin anemail@yahoo.com
    ServerAlias www.isellsoftwares.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/issoft
    ServerName isellsoftwares.com
    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

it still not working ...

i've added named file for this domain (( isellsoftwares.com.db ))

```
; Zone file for isellsoftwares.com
$TTL 14400
isellsoftwares.com.     86400   IN      SOA     ns1.isellsoftwares.com. elsolgan.yahoo.com.     (
                                                2012031500 ;Serial Number
                                                86400 ;refresh
                                                7200 ;retry
                                                3600000 ;expire
                                                86400 ;minimum
        )
isellsoftwares.com.     86400   IN      NS      ns1.isellsoftwares.com.
isellsoftwares.com.     86400   IN      NS      ns2.isellsoftwares.com.
isellsoftwares.com.     14400   IN      A       46.166.129.101
localhost       14400   IN      A       127.0.0.1
isellsoftwares.com.     14400   IN      MX      0       isellsoftwares.com.
mail    14400   IN      A       46.166.129.101
www     14400   IN      CNAME   isellsoftwares.com.
ftp     14400   IN      A       46.166.129.101
cpanel  14400   IN      A       46.166.129.101
whm     14400   IN      A       46.166.129.101
webmail 14400   IN      A       46.166.129.101
webdisk 14400   IN      A       46.166.129.101
ns1     14400   IN      A       46.166.129.101
ns2     14400   IN      A       46.166.129.101
```

but it still not working !!!!!

So, what else i should do??

Answer (score 1):

There are *many* things wrong with your configuration.

First, there are no public DNS records for ns1.isellsoftwares.com or ns2.isellsoftwares.com.  I would highly recommend you not host your own DNS on a single server you control.  Many registrars and hosting providers offer much better, redundant DNS hosting.

I queried Verizon and Google for your ns records using the following commands:

```
dig ns1.isellsoftwares.com @4.2.2.2
dig ns2.isellsoftwares.com @8.8.8.8
```

Next, if you did have the proper records pointing the nameserver name to the correct IP address, it's not able to be queried from the Internet.  By using `dig` again I can send a query directly to your DNS server:

```
dig isellsoftwares.com @46.166.129.101
```

However, this produced a REFUSED error:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3-RedHat-9.7.3-8.P3.el6_2.2 <<>> isellsoftwares.com @46.166.129.101
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 31993
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;isellsoftwares.com.        IN  A

;; Query time: 83 msec
;; SERVER: 46.166.129.101#53(46.166.129.101)
;; WHEN: Thu Mar 29 12:39:24 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 36
```

If I trick my local system to bypass DNS by adding the following to `/etc/hosts`, it works as advertised.

```
46.166.129.101  isellsoftwares.com www.isellsoftwares.com
```

Also, where did you get `/etc/nameserverips`, I've never heard of this file.

Comment: /etc/nameserverips File is responsible for The DNS (( DNS cannot be configured without this file )) 


you told me my problems, but did not tell me the solutions !

Comment: I've pointed out two configuration issues within your environment, I'm not sure how that equates to ".. did not tell me the solutions !".  I don't have enough information to step you through the exact processes required to resolve them.  Also, `/etc/nameserverips` is not part of the Linux DNS stack, nor any DNS server that I know of.  Perhaps it's specific to WHM/CPanel?  What DNS server are you running?